# htaccess redirection loose post data!! how to keep post data while redirect using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, post, url-rewriting

I have a `.htaccess` file that rewrite `.php` to `.htm`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^\s]+)\.php\s
RewriteRule .* %1.htm [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php
```

The redirect works fine, But the redirection looses the `$_POST` data. How to keep `$_POST` data while redirecting?

Comment: As long as the rule only rewrites the URL and doesn't perform an actual redirect, the `$_POST` data should be persistent over the rewrite.  It is still the same HTTP request after all...

Comment: You say that you want to rewrite `.php` to `.htm` but it seems that you are doing the opposite...  `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php` will change `.htm` URLS to `.php` URLS... Are you sure that your question reflects exactly what you want to do?

Comment: i want both, rewrite php to htm and redirect php to htm if user access the file in php .. and i need keep $_post data if exists while redirect from php to htm .. i hope i explain it correctly ..

Answer (score 1):

Browsers convert a POST request into a GET request on redirect. The [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) states that they should instead prompt the user if the method needs to change, but none of them follow that and instead force the method change unconditionally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply rewrite the URL from `.php` files to `.htm` files, all you'll need to do is something like this  -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^\s]+)\.php\s
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.htm
```

The 3 lines of the `.htaccess` detail the flowing behavior -

1. Turn on the rewrite engine
2. The request matches the given regular expression.
3. Rewrite the entire URL to use a `.htm` file.

Comment: i need both, rewrite and redirect, and keep $_POST data while redirct